# Not Able to Download Aptana Studio 3.4.0.zip for Windows 7?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, aptana, aptana3

> How can i download Aptana Studio 3.4.0 zipped version like eclipse.zip
>   I not allowed to download `.exe` files and i don't want to use Aptana as eclipse plugin .
>
> I found some links where older version of Aptana Stuio is available in zipped version but can anyone give me working link of latest Aptana Studio in zipped version
>
> Thank You ..